# Prepopulating form field to meet required condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that in some situations will have a pre populated value. To do this, I am using `placeholder`. If the `placeholder` value is not blank, I would like this to meet the `required` condition. Do I need a `Javascript` method or am I forgetting something simple?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
      Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="username" required>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> placeholder value is not blank, I would like this to meet the required
>   condition

Placeholder text is just displayed when you value is blank. Your required condition will be met if your 'value' is blank.

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="username" value="Pre populated Value" required/>
```

This should meet your required condition. As-is no JS is needed.

The above is of the assumption that placeholder is set by you. If you want placeholder to act as your 'value' attribute, yes you would need javascript.